# how to add the item of a dictionary inside another

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my condition.

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
 data = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'David', 'location': {'latitude': -12.2139, 'longitude': -77.0375}},
         {'id': '2', 'name': 'will', 'location': {'latitude': -22.2139, 'longitude': -87.0375}},
         {'id': '3', 'name': 'john', 'location': {'latitude': -32.2139, 'longitude': -97.0375}}]
```

The expected output is:

```
  data = [{'latitude': -12.2139, 'longitude': -77.0375,'name': 'David' },
          {'latitude': -22.2139, 'longitude': -87.0375, 'name': 'will'},
          {'latitude': -32.2139, 'longitude': -97.0375, 'name': 'john'}]
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you like to get the data from the *location* key inside the data you can use the following:

```
new_data = list() 
for item in data:
        tmp = dict()
        tmp['name'] = item.get('name')
        tmp.update(dict(item.get('location')))
        new_data.append(tmp)
#If you want the *data* to hold the variable:
#data = new_data
```

Or in a bit more confusing method:

```
data = [{'name': item.get('name'), **item.get('location')} for item in data]
```

This will results with the following output:

```
[{'name': 'David', 'latitude': -12.2139, 'longitude': -77.0375}, 
{'name': 'will', 'latitude': -22.2139, 'longitude': -87.0375}, 
{'name': 'john', 'latitude': -32.2139, 'longitude': -97.0375}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` comprehension with object unpacking.

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'David', 'location': {'latitude': -12.2139, 'longitude': -77.0375}},
         {'id': '2', 'name': 'will', 'location': {'latitude': -22.2139, 'longitude': -87.0375}},
         {'id': '3', 'name': 'john', 'location': {'latitude': -32.2139, 'longitude': -97.0375}}]
print([{'name': k['name'], **k['location']} for k in data])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'latitude': -12.2139, 'longitude': -77.0375, 'name': 'David'},
 {'latitude': -22.2139, 'longitude': -87.0375, 'name': 'will'},
 {'latitude': -32.2139, 'longitude': -97.0375, 'name': 'john'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer to my self.

```
l = []
for ele in data:
  loc = ele.get('location')
  name = ele.get('name')
  loc.update(name=name)
  l.append(loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily by using for.

```
[{**x['location'] ,**{"name":x["name"]}} for x in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = []
for dictionary in data:
    locationDict = dictionary["location"]
    locationDict["name"] = dictionary["name"]
    tmp.append(locationDict)

data = tmp
```

I would try this. For each dict, it takes the sub-dict and adds an additional value from the original dict.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy:

1. Get values from **data** having keys **location** and store them in variables
2. Again get values from **data** having keys **name** and append them to the variable used in number **1**
3. Print the value store in above variable

**[CODE]**

```
datas = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'David', 'location': {'latitude': -12.2139, 'longitude': -77.0375}}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'will', 'location': {'latitude': -22.2139, 'longitude': -87.0375}}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'john', 'location': {'latitude': -32.2139, 'longitude': -97.0375}}]

for data in datas:
    var = data['location']  # Getting value having key locations
    var['name'] = data['name']   # Appending value of key "name"

    ''' You can also append by following ways:

        var.update({'name': data['name']}

                      OR

        var.update({'name': data.get('name')})'''

    print(var)
```